# How do I disable PNG file "optimization" when building in MonoTouch?

Tags: optimization, xamarin.ios, png

I am making an application which uses a large amount of PNG file resources. In order to minimize the size of my binary, I have manually optimized all of my files, and was able to reduce the resources folder size to almost 20% of the original non-optimized size.

However, when building my application for device (not simulator) testing, the build process attempts to "optimize" my PNG files by running what seems to be a modified version of pngcrush, which not only makes the build process almost five minutes longer, and makes most of my files larger, but also makes some files unusable by doing alpha premultiplication, which I don't need, since I'm using the alpha values for purposes different than transparency.

I found that it is possible to disable this step in xcode, were I making an objective-c project, by changing "Compress PNG Files" to "No" in the Build Settings as described in [this webpage](http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html).

However, I have not been able to find how to modify this setting in the MonoDevelop project.

How do I disable this PNG "optimization" step when building from MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [feature](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1587) is being worked on (in MonoDevelop). However the iPhone addin (for MonoDevelop) is not open source so hacking it yourself won't work.

Right now you have two options.

1. Moving the image directly to the device during development so they won't be deployed each time (along with the application). You can see how to implement this hack from this [article](http://blog.xamarin.com/handling-large-assets-on-ios/).
2. Hack your `iphone-optimize` script (that's what MonoDevelop calls). The script tis located in your Xcode directory (if you have several version then the one specified in MonoDevelop's **SDK locations** is being used).

For this you need to:

1. Backup your existing (original) PNG;
2. Copy the optimized PNG as your 'new' originals;
3. Backup the `iphoneos-optimize` script;
4. Edit that script to ignore the PNG files (i.e. not execute pngcrush)

Keep in mind that updating Xcode will replace the script - so you'll need to re-edit it after updates.

Comment: Yeah, hacking `iphone-optimize` is what I ended up doing after reading the first answer. It's a simple perl script, so commenting out two lines did the trick. Option number 1 over there is a nice read, which I'll definitely keep in mind for the future. Even so, I think that this build step should be part of the MSBuild script for iPhone targets, that way it would be very customizable.

Comment: I don't really understand steps 1 and 2 over there. Just modifying `iphoneos-optimize` copied my manually optimized PNGs set to Content in the MonoDevelop project...

Comment: If you copied your optimized PNG then you have a *backup* copy of your original PNG (which was step #1). Step #2 means to set the *optimized* version (not the original) to be used in your application  (which you also did). So you followed the steps :-)

Comment: Just an FYI, MonoDevelop 4.0 no longer calls iphoneos-optimize, it now calls pngcrush directly. Currently, there's no bug report to disable the pngcrush step (but I'd be happy to implement it as soon as I have time). Could you submit a feature request to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com so I don't forget?

Comment: Just implemented this for MonoDevelop 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Half year ago it [was not possible](http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Using-ImageOptim-ImageAlpha-in-the-MT-build-cycle-td4589942.html).

Yet, since MonoDevelop sources are open, it is possible to patch it and compile from sources.

Comment: Without knowing the exact patch, and not being a MonoDevelop developer, that's simply _way_ too big an effort for such a simple thing (btw, MonoTouch seems to use a slightly different MonoDevelop. Is that one open as well?). However, that forum thread you mentioned explains that this step is performed by MonoDevelop, not by a call to xcode. (I would have really expected this to be part of the MSBuild script for iOS targets though). I'll try switching the pngcrush binary for something that does nothing and see what happens...

Comment: Yes, it is open source: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop. AFAIK, MonoDevelop "for" MonoTouch development, have no difference with MonoDevelop "for" Mono Droid development, except for platforms compatibility plugins for MonoDevelop.